# PuTTY is glitching out when I try to install wordpress

Tags: installation

I understand this is probably a pretty noob situation, but I can't for the life of me figure out [why it's doing this](https://i.imgur.com/EPe5jGw.gifv).

Any ideas on how to overcome this so I can get WP installed on my server? I've tried searching around for an answer, but apparently nobody else has ran into this issue.

The command entered is:

```
curl -O https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
```

The output is a bunch of gobltygook on the screen. Expected output is downloading the zipped file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl is outputting the response to the screen. You need to send the output to a file, like this:

```
curl https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz -o wordpress.tar.gz
```

Note the lowercase 'o', and the presence of a filename after that argument. You can name the file whatever you want. With this exact command, it will be downloaded into whatever folder you are currently in.

Comment: Thanks for this! I had actually been AFK after figuring out what the issue was, so haven't been able to come back to answer.

But apparently, it was an issue with my syntax. I was typing a zero, rather than a lowercase "o".

This is why I hate fonts sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

We were all noobs once :)

Try running the same command with wget:

```
wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
```

Than, you'll have to extract it with this command:

```
tar -xzvf latest.tar.gz
```

this will extract WordPress to a new directory called 'wordpress'

Good Luck!

Comment: this.  this is good.  As a side note you can ask for the latest.zip as well and then only have to remember unzip latest.zip